# Remove file from package reference

Tags: msbuild, nuget, csproj, nuget-package-restore, msbuild-task

I have a dependency on the NuGet library:

```
<ItemGroup>
  <PackageReference Include="OpenCvSharp4.Windows" Version="4.5.3.20210817" />
</ItemGroup>
```

This package adds the file `opencv_videoio_ffmpeg453_64.dll` to the bin folder, which makes some problems. I don't use FFmpeg and want to remove that file (OpenCV said that it is safe to remove it if you don't use FFmpeg backend).

So, I added these lines to the `csproj` file:

```
<Target Name="RemoveOpenCvFFmpeg" AfterTargets="AfterBuild">
  <Delete Files="$(OutDir)opencv_videoio_ffmpeg453_64.dll" />
</Target>
```

It works and everything is fine. But when I pack my project as a NuGet package, the **consumers** of our library still get that file in their bin folder and it also makes them some issues.

Is there any way to delete this file from the local build **and** from our package in some way, so our consumer won't get this file either?
Or pack them so the consumer will not restore `OpenCvSharp4.Windows` by its own (I use `msbuild /t:pack` for packing)

Comment: Hmmm but isn't that a strange behavior for your consumers if you're referencing `OpenCvSharp4.Windows`, but one of its assemblies is missing? Maybe it's a better option to make `OpenCvSharp4.Windows` a `PrivateAsset`, as stated [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/nuget/create-packages/select-assemblies-referenced-by-projects#recommended-one-assembly-per-package)

Comment: @mu88 I can make this a `PrivateAsset`, but maybe I missing something. `PrivateAsset` just **hides** things from the consumer. But the DLL will be still in the output directory, isn't it? Our project cannot run if it exists (some complex reasons)

Comment: I thought `PrivateAsset` would remove it, didn't know that

Comment: Let me please double check that and I will update here

Comment: @mu88 yes, after double checking, it just **hides** them for the consumer, the DLL is still in the `bin` folder